# Regular Expression to exclude substring

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to parse through a string with regular expressions (.NET) and find all custom tokens starting with `[[` and ending with `]]`. My first attempt was to use `\[\[(.*)\]\]`. This seemed to work when there was only one token in a string. But if there were multiple, it just return one result from the first `[[` to the very last `]]`.

My thought is to exclude `]]` from matching characters, but I've yet to find a way to get that working. I've tried using exclusion sets `(?! \]\])` and played around with different syntax, but can't find anything that actually works.

Anyone know an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are greedy by default, i.e. they consume as many characters as possible. To avoid this put a "?" after the ".*", i.e. try `\[\[(.*?)\]\]`.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. I forgot about the greedy concept of regex since I don't use it too much.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to escape those opening square brackets.  The OP did, but they didn't show up until I added code formatting.

Comment: @Alan Moore: thanks, I tried to go along with the OP. I just edited this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler than that, try using `.*?` (the last ? means it is an ungreedy match, meaning it will grab the bare minimum when catching the information).

For reference, please check out [this site on regex](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#Greedy). It will give you more details on greedy vs. ungreedy.

Comment: `.*?` will always match nothing.  I guess it doesn't get much simpler than that. :P

Comment: Heh, was more a segment of the original regex, but point noted. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

.* is a "greedy" match, and goes to the last match of your brackets.

*? specifies the first match that consumes as few repeats as possible (equivalent to lazy *)